# How can I provide an MS-Teams app to provide link-unfurling and nothing more?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have an MS Teams app that just does link unfurling. I do not want to provide any actions.
I use to be able to do this by just leaving the "commands" section in the manifest empty but now if I do that you get the oh so helpful message "Something went wrong".

So now the only way to get Teams to load my app is if I add a dummy command.

Is there some way to do this without providing commands or some way to provide a command that the user will never see?

**This is an actual manifest that fails:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.5",
  "version": "1.1",
  "id": "fe8ad7e8-7679-40d7-9435-0ef4488d74ce",
  "packageName": "com.foobar.teams.1",
  "developer": {
    "name": "foobar",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.foobar.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://foobar.com/en/privacy-policy/",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://foobar.com/en/terms-and-conditions/"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "foobar test",
    "full": "foobar test"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "foobar test",
    "full": "foobar test."
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "foobar-outline.png", 
    "color": "foobar-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "composeExtensions": [
  {
  "botId": "fe8ad7e8-7679-40d7-9435-0ef4488d74ce",
  "canUpdateConfiguration": false,
  "commands": [

      ],
      "messageHandlers": [
      {
        "type": "link",
        "value": {
          "domains": [
          "*.foobar.net"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
  ],
  "devicePermissions": [
  ],
  "validDomains": [
   "*.foobar.net" 
  ]
}
```

**This is a manifest that works**:
The only difference is that it contains commands.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.5",
  "version": "1.1",
  "id": "fe8ad7e8-7679-40d7-9435-0ef4488d74ce",
  "packageName": "com.foobar.teams.1",
  "developer": {
    "name": "foobar",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.foobar.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://foobar.com/en/privacy-policy/",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://foobar.com/en/terms-and-conditions/"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "foobar test",
    "full": "foobar test"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "foobar test",
    "full": "foobar test."
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "foobar-outline.png", 
    "color": "foobar-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "composeExtensions": [
  {
  "botId": "fe8ad7e8-7679-40d7-9435-0ef4488d74ce",
  "canUpdateConfiguration": false,
  "commands": [
       {
            "id": "shareMessage",
            "type": "action",
            "title": "Share Message",
            "description": "Test command to run action on message context (message sharing)",
            "initialRun": false,
            "fetchTask": false,
            "context": [
                "message"
            ],
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "includeImage",
                    "title": "Include Image",
                    "description": "Include image in Hero Card",
                    "inputType": "toggle"
                }
            ]
        }
],
      "messageHandlers": [
      {
        "type": "link",
        "value": {
          "domains": [
          "*.foobar.net"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
  ],
  "devicePermissions": [
  ],
  "validDomains": [
   "*.foobar.net" 
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @ Could you please check link [unfurling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/link-unfurling?tabs=dotnet) document.

Comment: Yes I have read that. Actually the example they give there of the manifest file is not valid. It will result in this error message: Error while reading manifest.json: "composeExtensions[0].commands" is required. Maybe I am missing something, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Leslie, Thanks for bringing it to our notice, we have reproved this from our end, you can pass empty command array inside the manifest. It is working for us. could you please check the below code snippet.
[image]

Comment: I still get the "Something went wrong" error when I have an empty command array.Do I need to update something to access your fix?

Comment: No changes required , just we need to pass empty command array, could you please share your manifest, we will try from our end, Mean while could you uninstall your app from app studio and re-install

Comment: I have opened a ticket with Microsoft support TrackingID#2104300010001696 I have also given them a link to this posting. They have a copy of my actuall manifest as well as some screen shots. Hopefully you can contyact them for the files. I do not want to post my actuall manifest here and I do not know how to get it to you directly.

Comment: I am not using app studio I am just using the MS Teams app and using "upload custom app".

Comment: Hi @B. Leslie, I think there is an issue with your manifest, we have tested with the default manifest by passing empty command array and its working fine.

Comment: I have updated my question to contain 2 complete manifests, one that works and one that doesn't. Maybe you can try them and see if they work for you. (Thanks for looking into this.)

Comment: I have the same problem. I can import the App into the Developer Portal without errors. However, the upload to teams fails: `POST https://teams.microsoft.com/api/.../appPackage/validate` causes 400 `App definition with message handler must have command.`

Comment: Adding the following unnecessary definition makes it work:
```"commands": [
                {
                    "id": "emptyCommand",
                    "description": "At least one command is required due to schema validation",
                    "title": "Ping",
                    "type": "action",
                    "fetchTask": true
                }
            ],
```